# Orthogonal projection of an $n-$vector onto the subspace ($m\leq n$)of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing a convex polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, polytopes

Lets say we have an $n \times m$ matrix $A$, whose column vectors are $(\vec{\mathbf{0}},a_1,a_2,...a_j)$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the non-zero vectors have unit length. Let $S:=\mathrm{span}\{a_i\}$. Now, we are given a trial vector, $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to determine if $v_{||S}$resides within the convex polytope formed from the column vectors of $A$.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Lets say that $A$ has a single non-zero column vector, $a_1$. Then the "polytope" will just be a line segment of length $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The projection of $v$ onto $S$ in this case can be found by solving the below equation:

$$v_{||a_1} = \lambda a_1: (v-\lambda a_1)\cdot a_1=0, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$

We can easily solve for $\lambda$:

$$\lambda = \frac{v \cdot a_1}{a_1 \cdot a_1}$$

Therefore, $v_{||a_1}$ is on the line segment formed by $a_1$ only if $\lambda \in [0,1]$

It seems that we can easily extend this to cases where there are more vectors in $A$ simply by verifying the above condition for each non-zero column vector of $A$. If the condition holds, then $v_{||S}$ must be inside the convex polytope formed by **all** the column vectors of $A$.

I was wondering if there was a rigorous proof of this or a counterexample?

Comment: what does $v_{||S}$ stand for ?

Comment: @sasha The orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the linear subspace $S$

Comment: is one column vector null for sure ?

Comment: @sasha yes, so that we can form the convex polytope form columns of A

Comment: last doubt are the rest of the column vectors linearly independent ?

Comment: @sasha no, they do not have to be linearly independent. Note however, that the requirement that they all have length 1 places some constraints on what the vectors in $A$ look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** 
The condition you give is necessary but not sufficient. Say a point is in the convex polytope so it can be written as ( here think of $v$ as projection of trial vector onto your subspace ) $v=\sum \lambda_j a_j$ where $\lambda_j$ are between 0 and 1 and sum upto 1. Now $v.a_k=\sum_j \lambda_j a_ja_k$ this will always be between 0 and 1 as all the $a_j$ are unit vectors for all $k$. But this is not a sufficient condtion. Say we have only two non zero column vector ( 2-D case ) $a_1=(1,0)$ and $a_2=(0,1)$ now if our trial vector is $v=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ ( projection of this vector onto your subspace is the vector itself  ) then its component along $a_1,a_2$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ but it does not lie inside the polytope.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for a proof or counterexample to my hypothesis that the projection of a vector into the subspace spanned by a polytope will be inside the convex polytope iff its projection onto each vector results in a $\lambda \in [0,1]$

Comment: please do comment if I have still understood your question wrongly or if there is some mistake in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Great, simple example...I slapped my forehead after you showed it to me. However, it does look like my criteria are sufficient for the projected point to lie in the polytope formed by all linear combinations of the column vectors using $\lambda_i\in [0,1]$, correct?

Comment: Since we are constraining $|v|<1$, this would reduce to a convex shape whose extremal edges are spherical sections, correct?

Comment: yes as I mentioned your criteria is necessary (  not sufficient ) as you are constraining your column vectors to be unit vectors

Comment: Thanks again! Very helpful response.